# projection from the filtering result of an array using jsonata

Tags: jsonata

I am interested in using jsonata to filter my json results, which is an array. I can use $[predicate] to filter the array, but how can I output the selected keys in each object? which means, to do project operations on each object in the result array?

Here is an example -

input:

```
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
  },
  {
    "a": 5,
    "b": 6,
    "c": 7
  }
]
```

expected result of selecting only a and c:

```
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "c": 3
  },
  {
    "a": 5,
    "c": 7
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this,

```
$ ~> |$|{}, ['b']|
```

*[here](https://try.jsonata.org/nwZtYVIn9) is simple demo*

Comment: Thanks, it works.  Two follow ups, firstly is the any document that explains the operators used in this example; Secondly, this doesn't seem graceful since it's by remove instead of select, what if I have so many keys, and I want to select a few specific keys? should I list all the keys that should be removed? Thanks.

Comment: 1) https://docs.jsonata.org/other-operators
2) `$.{ 'a': a, 'b': b }`